# Magento patch-SUPPEE-6285 not installing for V 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, patch, magento-1.9

i am trying to install Magento patch SUPEE-6825 for magento version 1.7.0.2 but i cam getting the below errors,  i couldn't find out what is the exact mistake i am doing, even though i am updated with all the latest released patches, please help me on this. i am getting the below error messages. Thanks in advance.

```
**$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
checking file app/Mage.php
checking file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 899
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|index 982ad5a..2bf6b37 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file downloader/Maged/.htaccess,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file downloader/lib/.htaccess,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file errors/processor.php**
```

Comment: Are you applying the same patch several times?

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75294/apply-patch-supee-6285

Comment: @Manashvi: So i have to revert the back the old theme and then once the patch was installed i have to replace with the current theme. Is that it works ...

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: is that we shouldn't apply a same patch continuously, if so what i have to do to make it a fresh install. Thanks in advance